# Thermal Printer not listed on Raspberry Pi under /dev/usb/lp0

Tags: raspberry-pi, thermal-printer

Operating System: Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit) with desktop Image with desktop based on Debian Buster (the 1.1G version)

I plugged in a ZJ58 thermal printer, but it cannot be accessed via the symlink /dev/usb/lp0 as usual on my other devices.

I ran `lsusb`

the output below shows the printer is connected.

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0416:5011 Winbond Electronics Corp. Virtual Com Port

The device is also visible at `/dev/bus/usb/001/004`

I ran `ls -al /dev/bus/usb/001`

device 004 has the group lp. This is why I assume the pi recognizes the thermal printer.

However, because the thermal printer is not accessible in /dev/usb/ as lp0 or lpx, x being any other number. I cannot run

`echo "testing\n testing\n testing" > /dev/usb/lp0` to print.

I tried `echo "testing\n testing\n testing" > /dev/bus/usb/001/004`. It does not work. The command line reports bash: echo: write error: invalid parameter.

Could anyone please point me to the right direction? I tried Googling and tried things listed below, but nothing helped.

`sudo apt install -y system-config-printer cups`
`sudo usermod -a -G lp pi`
`sudo apt install lprng`
`sudo apt install rp-prefapps`
`sudo apt -y dist-upgrade`
`echo 0416:5011:c > /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/quirks`

I tried blacklisting usblp as well, and it didn't work either.

Comment: There seems to be both parallel and serial patterns. [Thermal Printer driver for CUPS, Linux, and Raspberry Pi: zj-58](https://scruss.com/blog/2015/07/12/thermal-printer-driver-for-cups-linux-and-raspberry-pi-zj-58/), [Networked Thermal Printer using Raspberry Pi and CUPS](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/networked-thermal-printer-using-cups-and-raspberry-pi.pdf)

Comment: `dmesg | grep usblp` prints the following: `[9.767502] usblp: can't set desired altsetting 0 on interface 0`. This seems to suggest the POS printer I bought failed to respond to some system calls originating from the operating system, causing the system to be unable to mount the printer to the node /dev/usb/lp0. I bought a different POS printer to resolve this problem. The printer causing the issue seems to only work with Windows.